# Jwplayer flashing issue in chrome while scroll top and down

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jwplayer

I am facing the flashing issue while loading the jwplayer in my mac chrome.

Can anyone have any idea of why the jwplayer is flashing?

Comment: It works fine with the firefox in my mac.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by flashing issue? This is working for me in Chrome on my Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by adjusting the width in pixels instead of percentage.

39% to 650 pxs

Comment: hey, did you find any other solution

Comment: What problem you are facing? Can you give me a hint or a link?

Comment: Same issue (flashing/ blinking) the video on mac / crome

Comment: You need to adjust the width into pixels instead of %. That will do not make any moments while scroll.